# Split Landing Page (HTML, CSS, JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I watched the tutorial from Traversy Media for a Split Landing Page. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oRmQN244Ir0)

I wanted to tweak the page to have three sections instead of two, but i can't get it done.

It doesn't show the content of the left section. Instead the middle section is overlapping the left, and if i hover over it, the left section transitions into the middle.

Also if i hover over the middle section, no transition at all is being performed.

```js
const left = document.querySelector('.left');
const middle = document.querySelector('.middle');
const right = document.querySelector('.right');
const container = document.querySelector('.container');

left.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  container.classList.add('hover-left');
});

left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  container.classList.remove('hover-left');
});

middle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  container.classList.add('hover-middle');
});

middle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  container.classList.remove('hover-middle');
});

right.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  container.classList.add('hover-right');
});

right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  container.classList.remove('hover-right');
});
```

```css
:root {
  --container-bg-color: #333;
  --left-bg-color: rgba(223, 39, 39, 0.7);
  --left-button-hover-color: rgba(161, 11, 11, 0.3);
  --middle-bg-color: #ededed;
  --middle-button-hover-color: #ffba00;
  --right-bg-color: rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.8);
  --right-button-hover-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.3);
  --hover-width: 66%;
  --other-width: 16.5%;
  --speed: 1000ms;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 20%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.button {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 40%;
  height: 2.5rem;
  padding-top: 1.3rem;
  width: 15rem;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  border: #fff solid 0.2rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.split.left .button:hover {
  background-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
  border-color: var(--left-button-hover-color);
}

.split.middle .button:hover {
  background-color: var(--middle-button-hover-color);
  border-color: var(--middle-button-hover-color);
}

.split.right .button:hover {
  background-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
  border-color: var(--right-button-hover-color);
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--container-bg-color);
}

.split {
  position: absolute;
  width: 33%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.split.left {
  left: 0;
  background: url(/img/design.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.split.left:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--left-bg-color);
}

.split.middle {
  left:33.3%;
  background: url(/img/pexels.jpeg) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.split.middle:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--middle-bg-color);
}

.split.right {
  right: 0;
  background: url(/img/code.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.split.right:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--right-bg-color);
}

.split.left,
.split.right,
.split.middle,
.split.middle:before,
split.right:before,
split.left:before {
  transition: var(--speed) all ease-in-out;
}

.hover-left .left {
  width: var(--hover-width);
}

.hover-left .right {
  width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-left .middle {
  width: var(--other-width)
}

.hover-left .right:before {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-left .middle:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover-middle .middle {
  width: var(--hover-width);
}

.hover-middle .left {
  width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-middle .right {
  width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-middle .right:before {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-middle .left:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

.hover-right .right {
  width: var(--hover-width);
}

.hover-right .middle {
  width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-right .left {
  width: var(--other-width);
}

.hover-right .left:before {
  z-index: 1;
}

.hover-right .middle:before {
  z-index: 2;
}

@media(max-width:800px) {
  h1 {
    font-size: 2rem;
  }
  .button {
    width: 12rem;
  }
}

@media(max-height:700px) {
  .button {
    top: 70%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="split left">
    <h1>The Designer</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="split middle">
    <h1>The Noob</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
  </div>
  <div class="split right">
    <h1>The Programmer</h1>
    <a href="#" class="button">Read More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because your "left" section is in fact the middle one, you forgot to set position to the middle section .split.middle { left: 33%; } Then you just have to animate them all properly.

Comment: Thank you.
I set the split.middle to 33%, is there a possibility to set it centered, because on the right side theres still a bit from the background visible.
And the animation does not work properly, i can't find a way to fix it.
edit: i edited it above, you can run the code snippet to check it out!

Comment: I guess it's because you set .spit { width: 33%; }. try to set 33.3% instead

Comment: then theres on the left and on the right a bit from the background.
edited it above.
why do the transitions behave as they do? i really can't fix this

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things.

First you'll want to move the middle div when hovering on the three divs and move it back when exiting:

```
left.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    container.classList.add('hover-left');
    middle.style.left = "66.6666666%";
});

left.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    container.classList.remove('hover-left');
    middle.style.left = "33.333333%";
});

middle.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  container.classList.add('hover-middle');
  middle.style.left = "16.65%";
});

middle.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  container.classList.remove('hover-middle');
  middle.style.left = "33.333333%";
});

right.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  container.classList.add('hover-right');
  middle.style.left = "16.65%";
});

right.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  container.classList.remove('hover-right');
  middle.style.left = "33.333333%";
});
```

Also, you'll want to change the --hover-width to be 66.6%.

```
:root {
  --container-bg-color: #333;
  --left-bg-color: rgba(223, 39, 39, 0.7);
  --left-button-hover-color: rgba(161, 11, 11, 0.3);
  --middle-bg-color: #ededed;
  --middle-button-hover-color: #ffba00;
  --right-bg-color: rgba(43, 43, 43, 0.8);
  --right-button-hover-color: rgba(92, 92, 92, 0.3);
  --hover-width: 66.6666666%;
  --other-width: 16.65%;
  --speed: 1000ms;
}
```

The problem with the space between the middle div and the right div is that 33.3 + 33.3 + 33.3 = 99.9. So, you'll have to make up the .1% somewhere. So, lets close the gap. Use 33.333333 instead.

View this codepen: https://codepen.io/bpuhnk/pen/wxWKjj

Comment: upvote just for the "the noob" - section. Well written though